Parameters of the sampling distribution of the sample proportion
The sample proportion follows an approximately normal distribution provided certain conditions are met.
In other cases, the distribution is binomial (Source: https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/introstats/chapter/6-3-sampling-distribution-of-the-sample-proportion/).
Question: A binomial distribution has 2 parameters. What are the parameters (number of trials and probability of success) of the binomial variable (sample proportion) here? I understand that the probability of success is the population proportion. Just can't figure out the other parameter.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about economics and belongs on Cross Validated instead.

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$ is an i.i.d sample drawn from Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution, where $p$ is the population parameter, then the distribution of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$, where $n$ is the sample size, and $p$ is the population parameter. For $n$ large enough,
by CLT, the approximate distribution of the sample sum $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is $\text{Normal}$ with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$ and the approximate distribution of the sample proportion $\displaystyle\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{n}$ is $\text{Normal}$ with mean $p$ and variance $\dfrac{p(1-p)}{n}$.
